Sum an aggerated value in Django
I'm trying to achieve the following SQL query in Django:
(The table contains the purchases per each day per each location. I want to get the biggest amount of each location, then group them by state to see how much is the max that can be sold in each state)
select state, type, sum(amount)
    from (
        select l.state, dd.type, max(amount) as amount 
        from daily_data dd
        join locations l on l.id = dd.location_id
        where dd.type in ('purchases', 'returns')
        group by dd.location_id, dd.type
    )
    group by state, type

Where I get this:
NY,purchases,80
NY, returns,6
Maine,purchases,125
Maine, returns,12

But I'm geting stuck on how to achieve that in django.
I tried this:
daily_data.objects.filter(type__in=['purchases', 'returns']
        ).values('location', 'type'
        ).annotate(total=Max('amount')
        ).values('location__state','type'
        ).annotate(sum=Sum('total'))

But I get an error django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('total'): 'total' is an aggregate
I even tried a subquery, but this is generating a bad sql query which yields the query taking forever.
subquery = daily_data.objects.filter(
    location=OuterRef('location'),
    type=OuterRef('type')
).values('location', 'type').annotate(
    max_amount=Max('amount')
).values('max_amount')

annotated_data = daily_data.objects.filter(
    type__in=['purchases', 'returns']
).annotate(
    max_amount=Subquery(subquery)
).values(
    'location__state', 'type'
).annotate(
    total_max_amount=Sum('max_amount')
).order_by('location__state', 'type')

This generates:
SELECT "state", "type", SUM((
        SELECT MAX(U0."amount") AS "total" FROM "daily_data" U0
        INNER JOIN "locations" U1 ON (U0."location_id" = U1."id")
        WHERE (U1."state" = ("state") AND U2."type" = "type") GROUP BY U0."location_id", U2."type")) AS "total"
FROM "daily_data"
    INNER JOIN "locations" ON ("location_id" = "locations"."id") WHERE where "type" in ('purchases', 'returns')
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             GROUP BY "state", "type"

which is redundant and expensive... And I didn't get to see the result yet as it's loading forever...

Hi there I am not an expert in django orm, but for me when programmatic creation of a query gets for complex when using django or spring (java framework), I often just prefer to write my sql directly and django provides you with that
django raw sql
where you can just
     result=daily_data.objects.raw(
        """
            select state, type, sum(amount)
            from (
                select l.state, dd.type, max(amount) as amount 
                from daily_data dd
                join locations l on l.id = dd.location_id
                where dd.type in ('purchases', 'returns')
                group by dd.location_id, dd.type
            )
            group by state, type
        """
    )

    for value in result.iterator():
        print(value)

and use iterator to see the values, although this is just a suggestion hope it might help :)
note: please make sure to follow the documentation while using the raw method to prevent sql injection.

Thanks. But this has many limitations. It's funny that Django shouldn't have a standard approach for that.

At the end I think I'll have to stick to your solution... Django does not support aggerating an aggerated value with the ORM syntax.
(Sorry that I can't upvote your post yet as I don't have enough reputation...)

@JaWe The most important part is that you found a solution and that is what programming is about, one solution dose not work ,just try to use another or make one up, hope I was helpful have a great day :)
